# Fixing outliers with an user defined function

Tags: python, numpy, outliers

I am trying to write a function which will fix the outliers in the dataset. i.e. If the outlier is above the upper bound the value will be replaced with upper bound and if the value is lesser than lower bound it will be replaced with lower bound. The function I created is listed below.

```
def fix_outliers(df):
    anomalies = []
    df_std = np.std(df)
    df_mean = np.mean(df)
    anomaly_cut_off = df_std * 3
    lower_limit  = df_mean - anomaly_cut_off 
    upper_limit = df_mean + anomaly_cut_off
    df=np.where(df > upper_limit, upper_limit, df)
    df=np.where(df < lower_limit, lower_limit, df)
```

The changes happening inside the function is not getting changed in my dataset.
I am new to python and especially with functions. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vin

Comment: is the input (df) a pandas dataframe? or are you just looking at numpy arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proposition:

```
def fix_outliers(df):

    df_fx=df.copy()
    df_fx_mean=np.nanmean(df_fx)
    df_fx_std=np.nanstd(df_fx)

    upper_limit=df_fx_mean+3*df_fx_std
    lower_limit=df_fx_mean-3*df_fx_std

    df_fx[df_fx>upper_limit]=upper_limit
    df_fx[df_fx<lower_limit]=lower_limit

    return df_fx

df_fixed=fix_outliers(df)
```

I think it's better to create a copy of the dataframe and then modify it instead of loosing the raw data. If you still only want to modify df:

```
def fix_outliers(df):
    
    df_mean=np.nanmean(df)
    df_std=np.nanstd(df)

    upper_limit=df_mean+3*df_std
    lower_limit=df_mean-3*df_std

    df[df>upper_limit]=upper_limit
    df[df<lower_limit]=lower_limit
   

fix_outliers(df)
```

Comment: you compute mean and std twice

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the question correctly, the input is a pandas dataframe. If that's the case, here's a solution:

```
NUM_STD = 3 # not strictly needed. Defines what's an outlier. 

def outliers(df):
    df[df > (df.std() * NUM_STD + df.mean())] = list(df.std() * NUM_STD + df.mean())
    df[df < (df.mean() - df.std() * NUM_STD)] = list(df.mean() - df.std() * NUM_STD)
    return df

# for demo purposes - create a dataframe and run outliers. 
normal_dist = lambda : np.random.normal(loc = 100, scale = 50, size = 100)
df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : normal_dist(), "b": normal_dist()})
outliers(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes are not visible outside of your function because `np.where` creates a *new* array. The variables in Python behave like label pointing to objects (kind-of similar to C pointers). Therefore operation:

```
df = <something>
```

will update the label `df` but it will *not* change object that `df` was pointing to.

Proper update would look like this:

```
df[df > upper_limit] = upper_limit
df[df < lower_limit] = lower_limit
```

BTW. There is numpy function dedicated for this task. It is [`np.clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html).
The operation can be squashed to:

```
np.clip(df, lower_limit, upper_limit, out=df)
```

The final function would be:

```
def fix_outliers(df):
    df_std = np.std(df)
    df_mean = np.mean(df)
    anomaly_cut_off = df_std * 3
    lower_limit  = df_mean - anomaly_cut_off 
    upper_limit = df_mean + anomaly_cut_off
    np.clip(df, lower_limit, upper_limit, out=df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the code you have provided:

```
def fix_outliers(df):
    df_std = np.std(df)
    df_mean = np.mean(df)
    anomaly_cut_off = df_std * 3
    lower_limit  = df_mean - anomaly_cut_off 
    upper_limit = df_mean + anomaly_cut_off

    for col in df.columns:
        for i in range(df.shape[0]):
            if df[col][i] > upper_limit[col]:
                df[col][i] = upper_limit[col]
            elif df[col][i] < lower_limit[col]:
                df[col][i] = lower_limit[col]

    return df
```